# Breaking paragraph according to content

Tags: html, css, sass, html-email

I'm developing an email template for further automation with Mautic. I encountered an issue with wrapping my header which should be broken into 2 lines.

## What is needed?

IF the total width doesn't exceed the width of the containing `<td>` is:

- *salutation* on the 1-st line
- *title* and *name* on the 2-nd line

Example:

> Greetings
> Mr Lee

or

> Greetings
> Mrs Henderson

IF *title* and *name* on the second line are wider than the containing `<td>`, title should join *salutation* on the 1-st line.

Example:

> Greetings Mrs
> Henderson-Lee

All the styling will be inlined in the markup prior to moving it to Mautic.

## What did I try?

I tried combinations of `&nbsp;`, `<wbr>`, `<pre>` as well as a range of CSS properties including `width`, `display`, `white-space`, `word-break` or `overflow-wrap`. I was unable to combine it in a way, that would work for all 3 examples.

Comment: Not possible with CSS itself, you need server side script to change the display of the title and name (block/inline) depending of char number in total.

Comment: Might be a stupid question but have you tried `<br>` if you are using two values as merge tags?

Comment: @Syfer can you elaborate please?

Comment: Was just thinking that this content might be only for emails and if you append your source data with `<br>` or add a `<br>` between the two variable in your source then it would create a line break.

Comment: @Syfer I think he's wanting it dynamic such that sometimes there'll be a break, and sometimes there won't be - depending on what fits. So hardcoding a <br> after the salutation won't work for all cases.

Comment: @Nathan I had taken that into account. My comment is more based on OP having control over data. If he has control over data then it should be possible, right?

Comment: @Syfer I think even if he edits the data and inserts breaks into the raw data, that won't take into account variations when it hits inboxs and suddenly it's mobile and everything is squeezed

Comment: @Syfer the name variable will be used in multiple places, so hardcoding <br> would bring trouble elsewhere. Also, the font used is not monospace, so the letter count does not predictably translate to the length of the paragraph (e.g. "i" has third the width of "w").

Answer (score 0):

This can't be achieved in any meaningful sense, even with a server-side solution.

There are potentially infinite variations that your email will be rendered in (considering mobiles, tablets, desktops, as well as variations on different operating systems, as well as variations based on individual settings, and the list goes on).

What you perfect in one email client will be different in another.

So the width of your `<td>` may change depending on the email client that receives it.

Some email clients like Gmail may even change your font.

Comment: Understood. Just for clarification: the width of the table is fixed to 640px and the layout is not responsive.

Comment: ok. So regardless, email clients, particularly mobiles and tablets - but some desktops too - will change/scale your table. So you shouldn't try to build pixel perfect layouts. That's not a workable way forward. You should aim to build the best possible experience for each email client.